# What are the benefits of installing jdt on top of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I refer to this link: http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/02/how-to-install-eclipse-ide-on-ubuntu-11-10/

I installed eclipse using this command: sudo apt-get install eclipse

Then i wondering is there any good reason to install sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt also?

Basically what extra functionality exactly do eclipse-jdt offers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article indicates that the eclipse package is *Eclipse - the platform* and not *Eclipse - the Java IDE*. I don't know if it's true or not, but if it is, then installing the eclipse-jdt package is a must if you want to develop in Java, as installing eclipse-cdt is a must if you want to develop in C++.

If the article is wrong, and eclipse is the full Java IDE, installing eclipse-jdt is indeed unnecessary.